# Angular scroll top after route changes interfere with relative url changes

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-routerlink

I have enabled the `scrollPositionRestoration` in my app-routing module as it follows:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })]
```

But this creates conflicts when I try to make the user scroll to the page with routerLink, here's an example:

```
<li><a routerLink="/" fragment='servizi'>{{ "NAV_SERVIZI" | translate }}</a></li>
```

When the user clicks on the link, the url is compiled correctly: [www.website.com/#servizi](http://www.website.com/#servizi), while the user's redirect on the top of the page instead of at the middle, where the #servizi element is.

How can I enable the `scrollPositionRestoration` behavior only for page changes while preserving normal scrolling when I redirect the user within the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set anchorScrolling: 'enabled'

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { 
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' 
})]
```

https://angular.io/api/router/InMemoryScrollingOptions#anchorScrolling